# Parsing string of numbers not registering 0 in Python3

Tags: python

I have this code to reformat a string in Python. So 'abc123' could be 'a1b2c3' or '1a2b3c' or '1b3a2c' and so on. Basically permutations where the rule is a letter follows a number and a number follows a letter.  It works for every case except for 1 as far as I can tell. When a zero exists somewhere in the string, the program completely disregards it when parsing as if it were a blank space. So if input is '0abc12' the output becomes 'a1b2c' when it should be '0a1b2c'. How can I fix this?

```py
def reformat(s: str) -> str:
    nums = []
    chars = []
    new_str = ""
    for char in s:
        try:
            if int(char):
                nums.append(char)
        except ValueError:
            chars.append(char)
    if len(chars) == len(nums):
        for i in range(len(chars)):
            new_str += chars[i] + nums[i]
    elif len(chars) == len(nums) + 1:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            new_str += chars[i] + nums[i]
        new_str += chars[-1]
    elif len(nums) == len(chars) + 1:
        for i in range(len(chars)):
            new_str += nums[i] + chars[i]
        new_str += nums[-1]
    else:
        new_str = ""
    return new_str
```

Comment: Have you done any debugging? I would recommend reading https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/. Hint: Focus on `if int(char):`

Comment: Also, it might help if you explain the intended behaviour of the function.

Comment: @AMC I tried as much debugging as I could. You were correct about the int(char). It needed an extra clause for the if statement to verify 0. Thank you for the resource on debugging!

Comment: _You were correct about the int(char). It needed an extra clause for the if statement to verify 0._ Even better, just replace the whole thing with [`str.isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit), or [`string.digits`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.digits).

Answer (score 0):

this line: `if int(char):` is the issue.

`int('0')` equates to `0` - and the statement `if 0:` is the same as `if False:` - hence the following line does not run when the char is 0.

Try removing the if statement, the try except clauses should be enough.

Comment: I need to check if char is an int so that's why the if int(char): is necessary. I did however add an additional clause to the statement to check if char =='0' and that cleared up the issue.